# How to permanently change CSS for selected cells in Jupyter notebook

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Depending on whether some variable is set or not, I want my cells to displayed with a different background color. This means that I cannot solve my problem by statically changing the `.jupyter/custom.css`

**Attempts:**

**1:**

I tried doing this by calling

```
display(HTML("<style>.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected { background:red }</style>"))
```

whenever the variable is set to `True`
and

```
display(HTML("<style>.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected { background:red }</style>"))
```

whenever the variable is set to `False`. However, this only changes the cell background color for as long as the cell where the `display` was executed is displayed.

**2:**

I tried using javascript

```
display(HTML("""<script>$('.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected').css({'background-color' : 'green'});<script>""")
```

but this permanently changes the background of the cell where I execute this, whereas I want to change the background of whatever cell is select at any given point.